# How to disable lazy load in specific page

Tags: wordpress, html

In site www.elektronka.sk i have activated lazy load on scroll down

Please help me to disable lazy load on scroll **only one page**:

http://www.elektronka.sk/aktualny-letak/

the content show after scroll down, i need to disable it, and show content without scroll

the script is here:

```
<script id="elm-services-_e0be74666bb9c4-script">
jQuery(window).load(function(){

    if(!isResponsive(1024)){
        jQuery("#elm-services-_e0be74666bb9c4-main").waypoint(function(){
            jQuery("#elm-services-_e0be74666bb9c4-main").addClass('load-finished');
        }, { triggerOnce: true, offset: "95%" });
    } else {
        jQuery("#elm-services-_e0be74666bb9c4-main").addClass('load-finished');
    }
  });
</script>
```

how to disable "**load-finished**" only for this one page?

Please advise ,thanks

Comment: what plugin you use?

Comment: Hi,i do not use plug-in ,its integrated in theme fuctions

Answer (score 1):

You can load scripts only on specific pages using this code in your functions files.

```
// Load conditional scripts
function conditional_scripts()
{
    // test if you are on the right page.
    if (is_page('pagenamehere')) {
        wp_register_script('scriptname', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scriptname.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Conditional script(s)
        wp_enqueue_script('scriptname'); // Enqueue it!
    }
}
```

Oops don't forget to add

```
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'conditional_scripts');
```

It might be possible to test other things than page name suchas page templates or page categories.

Regards

Alex

Comment: Hi,thank you! Its disable scripts for specific page?  i must add the script to '/js/scriptname.js' ?

Comment: add the script in a js folder in your theme's folder and change 'scriptname.js' by your scriptname.

Comment: Hi, its possible to add to functions.php only condition if i have page 'pagenamehere' , disable jQuery(window).load(function() script?

Comment: No you cannot disable a single function, only a whole script file. You can however put only one function in a javascript file. Add jQuery(window).load(function() to a javascript file named 'yourscript.js', and remove it from your main javascript file.